# Does Lansweeper scan your home network?

Tags: networking

I have Lansweeper running on the company issued device.

I know it is running because activity monitor shows `LSAgent` as a running process. Then using `ps aux` I saw the directory of the process: `/Applications/LansweeperAgent/LSAgent`.

The information on Lansweeper online is very corporate and hidden.

1. Is this application scanning the local network devices?
2. Is it sending other device and network information to a lansweeper server?

Comment: Define "privacy". There are a million different ways to think about privacy violations, and ours might not match yours. If you're thinking for example making a list of all MAC addresses on your network, Windows does that all by itself already. Is that a privacy violation? I dunno...

Comment: Fair enough. I have updated the question.

Comment: @no_step_on_snek yeah [Lansweeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lansweeper) scans the devices on your network, hence the name. You can probably use wireshark to figure out how much of this info they are phoning home. Or you can just contact support.

Comment: `I know this due to Activity monitor showing LSAgent at 100% CPU.` .. no, you don't.  You are *probably* correct but CPU usage does not equate to anything but CPU usage.  For all you know it is in a tight loop checking free drive space.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I meant I know Lansweeper is running because...

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas His conclusion is correct, there is no need to correct his statement. The existence of a process is a spot on indication that some program was executed and is currently running. Of course it is no metric for **what** a program is currently doing, but that doesn't matter here, as the question was only about the mere existence and purpose of the software, not about a fault state or similar. Please keep comments on topic.

Comment: @mashuptwice , I didn't correct his statement.  I was merely pointing out that because an app is at 100% cpu, one can only guess what it is doing based that one and only metric.  We are all here to teach.  We are all here to learn.  Thank you for your comment though.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the decrypted traffic and the log in `/Applications/LansweeperAgent/lsagentlog.txt`

1. The agent makes a form POST to `/lsagent` on the lansweeper server.
   With `AssetId`, `OperatingSystem` and `Action=AssetStatus`. The server responds with `Status=Enabled`
2. The agent makes another form POST to `/lsagent` with the above fields and `Action=Config`. The server responds with `xml` that is an `ArrayOfLsAfentConfigItem` - which seems to be configuration the lsagent uses - serial numbers and when to run scans or updates.
3. For the trial version that is where it ended. On the non trial version it made a 3rd request: A POST to `/lsagent` with `Action=Scan` and a filename="Scan" and binary data that was `10.3kb`.

I noticed with the trial version - that the computer with the agent on sent more detailed information to the server - the exact hardware (+ screens and peripherals) and all the software installed and the particular version it was on.

1. Is this application scanning the local network devices?

Yes, the server is. The agent does not appear to be.

2. Is it sending other device and network information to a lansweeper server?

Not as far as I can see. Only the device sotware and versions are sent to the lansweeper server.